# calculate maximum salary for all employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table called EMPLOYEE with 17 different columns. One column is called Salary which is the column that shows all the employees salary. I am trying to calculate the maximum salary and I know it's not the right answer. The highest salary in the column is 131250 and with the statement it continues to pull up that value. Not sure why it's not calculating all the employees.

SELECT MAX(CAST(Salary as MONEY)) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee

Result = 131250

At first the datatype was varchar, then I changed it to money and next int and still not good. What could be the problem?

Comment: In what way is it "not good"? Is it not formatted right or is it the wrong number? Could you post your table structure?

Comment: Robert, thanks. I have been trying to at least take a screen shot of the column with the salaries. However, not sure why I can't paste it here.

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  For instance, it doesn't mention the table `EMPLOYEE`.

Comment: Let me get this straight: 1. you want the highest salary in the table. 2. You know that the highest salary is `131250`. 3. Your query is constantly pulling that value. Is that right?

Comment: @jeffchambers from your comments on some of the answers, do you want the [average](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+average)?

Comment: @Terminus no, what I am looking for is trying to get the maximum salary for all employees. There are 17 individuals and I was thinking it should calculate all 17 of those different salaries and post the maximum of what each one could earn. The answer I got was $27,583 when I did it the old fashioned way with a calculator. So, with the SQL statement something is left out to where I am not getting the answer that was mentioned.

Comment: Could you post some of your data? I can't figure out what you mean. It sounds like you want the maximum salaray but that's what you are already pulling so you must mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

SELECT MAX(CAST(salary as DECIMAL(12,2))) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee

Answer (score 1):

You may have meant to put `SELECT MAX(CAST(Salary as MONEY)) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee WHERE Salary = X` but honestly to find the maximum, you'll want no `WHERE` clause involved so just remove the `= 131250`

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to make this confusing I was just showing at the end I was getting 131250 which is not right.

Comment: Milo, in the where clause what do I need to add?

Comment: @Jeff Chambers Nothing. `SELECT MAX(CAST(Salary as MONEY)) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee` without a where clause would get you your maximum salary.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove this part '= 131250' and try to see the output??

Comment: Maybe I am not wording the question correctly. I am trying to calculate the maximum salary for all employees. ONE employee has a salary of 131250, but that shouldn't be the answer if I am trying to calculate all the salaries and it should come up with a different answer

Comment: I think what you want is the average and not the maximum salary of your employee.

Comment: remember the table is called Employee

Comment: To get the Average Salary.. 
SELECT AVG(CAST(salary as DECIMAL(12,2))) AS Average_Salary FROM Employee

To get the Highest Salary..
SELECT MAX(CAST(salary as DECIMAL(12,2))) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee

Comment: Hey darkangel, I have tried the second statement and that still did not work. I am trying to find the maximum salary of all employees.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX(Convert(Money,Salary)) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee

Comment: Everyone I just did it the old way in using a calculator and the average max salary is 27,583 that is what I should be getting. Remember it is all the employees which are 17 individuals with different salaries so, I add it all up and then divide it by 17 which gave me that answer.

Comment: "average max salary" is nonsensical. Do you want the average salary, or the max salary?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find max salary or average salary?

Max salary

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(Salary as MONEY)) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee
```

Average salary

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(Salary as MONEY)) AS Highest_Salary FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max salary of each employee you can use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(Salary) as MONEY) AS Highest_Salary
FROM Employee
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

If you then want to get the average of that you can use your application, or run this other query.

```
SELECT CAST(AVERAGE(Highest_Salary) as MONEY) as avg_salary
FROM (
  SELECT CAST(MAX(Salary) as MONEY) AS Highest_Salary
  FROM Employee
  GROUP BY EmployeeID
) high_salaries
```